# pointer malloc fail

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I tried to define a node struct which includes a node* next. I write an `append(node* n）` function to add a new node next to the previous one， but every time I run the code, it gives me seg fault. My code is following:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>


typedef struct _log_t {
  struct _log_t* next;
}log_t;

void initi(log_t* l) {
  l = (log_t*)malloc(sizeof(log_t));
  l -> next = NULL;
}

void append(log_t* l){
  l->next = (log_t*)malloc(sizeof(log_t)); 
  l->next->next = NULL;
  l = l->next;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 6):

```
 l = l->next;
```

That line is not doing what you think it is - in fact, its doing nothing.

Perhaps you want to pass log_t* as a `log_t**`, or return the new `log_t*`.

Answer (score -2):

You're dereference a pointer you never initialized.  That's why it's crashing :)

```
// OK (but you should check for malloc() failing, too!)
void initi(log_t* l) {
  l = (log_t*)malloc(sizeof(log_t));
  l -> next = NULL;
}

void append(log_t* l){
  // OK...
  l->next = (log_t*)malloc(sizeof(log_t)); 
  // BAD!!!!  l->next: allocated.  l->next->next: *NOT* initialized!
  l->next->next = NULL;
  l = l->next;
}
```

Here's what I *think* you *possibly* mean:

```
log_t * append (log_t* l) {
  // Initialize the head
  if (l == NULL) {
    l = (log_t *)malloc(sizeof (log_t));
    l->next = NULL;
  }
  // Initialize a sub-node
  else {
    l->next = (log_t *)malloc(sizeof (log_t));
    l->next->next = NULL;
  }
  // Always return the head
  return l;
}
```

Comment: hi is just doing the initalization... perfectly fine. there is no dereferencing.

Comment: that update is even worse.. append(NULL).. that's just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @yi_H: the point is you can't dereference "l->next->next" until you've both 1) allocated "l", and 2) initialized "l->next".  It's perfectly appropriate to initialize l->next either to NULL, or to a newly allocated value.  It's *NOT* OK to use it *BEFORE* you've initialized it.

Comment: you should take a rest, then re-read this thing, because you're talking nonsense. he allocated the memory in the previous line.